Apache flink not emitting records on windowing of socket stream
I'm fetching data from socketstream and assigning watermark, with 20 seconds of outoforderboundedness then converting to keyed stream
On windowing the keyed stream I'm not able to see any records in output
keyedStream
    .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(7), Time.seconds(2)))
    .allowedLateness(Time.seconds(20))
    .process(new CustomKeyedProcessFunction())
    .print();

I tried the above code for

Reading the data from file it works fine.
Tried giving idleness of 2 minutes still no output
Tried removing window, allowed lateness and process function then keyed stream is working fine having watermark and printing the output
With the help of Count Trigger I'm able to view the result

Issue is window is not able to emit the records with the code mentioned and not emitting without trigger, Need help if the issue is particularly in socket stream/idleness or anything else?

Assigning watermark is important while windowing the real-time streaming,

In above case the socket stream was waiting for the late event threshold of the watermark to be passed, once it had passed the threshold of delay it sent the data downstream
